# Change UI color based on a condition in Xcode with SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, if-statement, swiftui

I am trying to change the color on animation applied on a swipe gesture but its not working. Is there any logical error that i am unable to find ? kindly help.

the if condition that i am using

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = RecipeManager()
    @Namespace private var viewSpace
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if manager.currentRecipeIndex % 2 == 0 {
                Color.lightBackground
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            } else {
                Color.darkBackground
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
            
            
            RecipeOverview(manager: manager, viewSpace: viewSpace)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
          
            if manager.selectedRecipe != nil {
                RecipeDetailView(manager: manager, viewSpace: viewSpace)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the extension to the color

```
extension Color {
    static let lightBackground = Color.init(red: 243/255, green: 243/255, blue: 243/255)
    static let darkBackground = Color.init(red: 34/255, green: 51/255, blue: 68/255)
}
```

The program keeps showing the white screen. but if change the if condition to show the darkBackground then it does not show the white screen while executing the else statement.

Comment: For starters, you're treating the `Color` as a view, for a background color, which is not necessary. Simply add a modifier to your `ZStack`, `.background()` Then in the background put your condition there. That would ensure that your background color is truly in the back layer, and you don't need all those extra modifiers. That's purely an best practices change, however I'd be interested to see your `RecipeManager()` object, I suspect that the problem exists there, not in your view.

Comment: where is your swipe gesture? what is changing `manager.currentRecipeIndex`?

Comment: here is the link to git of my project

https://github.com/vagues0ul/recipeApp/tree/main/DailyCookingQuest